# How to access index number within lapply

Tags: r, indexing, apply, lapply

Say that I have this `lapply`:

```
set.seed(123)
a2 <- lapply(12:14, 
            function(x) {
                a <- data.frame(value=x+round(rnorm(1),1))
                #a$new <- 
                a
            }
)
```

This produces:

```
> a2
[[1]]
  value
1  11.4

[[2]]
  value
1  12.8

[[3]]
  value
1  15.6
```

What I would like is to also have a column with the index number of the list element, so the first would be `1`, the second `2`, and the third `3`. In other words, the number within the `[[ ]]`. Importantly, I would like to be able to do this all within the `lapply`.

Note that here is how I would do this using a loop:

```
for(i in 1:length(a2)) {
    a2[[i]]$new <- i
}
```

The desired result:

```
> a2
[[1]]
  value new
1  11.4   1

[[2]]
  value new
1  12.8   2

[[3]]
  value new
1  15.6   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` on the sequence of the `list` and `cbind`

```
Map(cbind, a2, new = seq_along(a2))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
  value new
1  11.4   1

[[2]]
  value new
1  12.8   2

[[3]]
  value new
1  15.6   3
```

---

A similar approach with `imap`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
imap(a2, ~ .x %>%
     mutate(new = .y))
```

---

Or if we need `lapply`, loop over the sequence, extract the `list` element with `[[` and `transform` or `cbind`

```
lapply(seq_along(a2), function(i) cbind(a2[[i]], new = i))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
  value new
1  11.4   1

[[2]]
  value new
1  12.8   2

[[3]]
  value new
1  15.6   3
```